# не выводится migx modx revo

Tags: cms, modx, revo, ресурсы

подскажите , почему может не выводить тв migx

вот сам вывод

```
          [[!getResources?
      &parents=`10`
      &showHidden=`1`
      &tpl=`lostAuto`
      &includeContent=`1`
      &includeTVs=`1`
      &processTVs=`1`
      &tvPrefix=``
      &limit=`1`
      ]]
```

и сам чанк:

```
<div class="cars_id">
                    <div class="views">Просмотров 1944</div>
                </div>
                <h1><strong>[[+pagetitle]]</strong></h1>
                <div class="car_image_wrapper car_group">
                    <div class="big_image">
                        <a href="[[+tvautoSale]]" class="car_group">
                            <img src="assets/images/zoom.png" alt="" class="zoom"/>
                            <img src="[[+tvautoSale]]" alt=""/>

                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="small_img">
                        [[getImageList?
                          &tvname=`galleryc`
                          &tpl=`smallimgTpl`
                         ]]
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="car_characteristics">
                    <a href="#" class="print"></a>
                    <div class="price">[[+price]]$ <span>* Договорная</span></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="features_table">
                        <div class="line grey_area">
                            <div class="left">Модель:</div>
                            <div class="right">[[+model]]</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="line">
                            <div class="left">Тип кузова:</div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="info_box">
                    <div class="car_info">
                        <div class="center">
                            <h2><strong>Описание</strong></h2>
                            [[+content]]
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
```

и чанк вывода тв migx

```
<a href="[[+image]]" class="car_group">
```

Answer (score 1):

Не указан docid у вызова getImageList. Читайте документацию прежде чем задавать такие вопросы - https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/migx/migx.frontend-usage